# what is the correct way to collect input data WITHOUT LAG on typing in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik, formik-material-ui

so it's been a month i'm working with react.

there is a problem i didn't know what to do with it.

in `onChange event handlers` EVEN in the smallest page and project there is a delay in typing and specially Delay in `Removing text`.

why is this happenig ?
i mean react is popular because of Fast UI right? so what we should do to handle Forms without this Perfomance Problem ?

why there is a lag in this form ?

```js
const LoginForm = () => {
  // State & Validate Schema
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      rememberMe: false,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
     blah blah some validation
    }),
    onSubmit: (value) => {
       console.log(value, "Submitted");
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="sm" disableGutters>
        <Box>
          <h3>Log to the Account</h3>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                error={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email !== undefined}
                name='email'
                label='Email'
                value={formik.values.name}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur} // If Input is Touched Show Error
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                autoComplete="on"
                              />
                <TextField
                error={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password!== undefined}
                name='password'
                label='Password'
                value={formik.values.password}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                helperText={formik.touched.password&& formik.errors.password}
                autoComplete="on"
                              />
                  <Button type="submit" variant="contained" size="medium">
                    Login
                  </Button>
                  <span>Remember Me</span>
                  <Checkbox
                    value={formik.values.rememberMe}
                    name="rememberMe"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  />
          </form>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem of react rather than Formik. In your example you have a variable named `formik` to pass the current value to your `TextField` component you define the prop `value={formik.values.someName}` and to update the field value you specify an `onChange={formik.handleChange}` handler. To be able to pass the new value after a change to your input field, the `formik` variable needs to be updated and this causes your whole form component to be rerendered on every key stroke.

To be honest, I switched for similar reasons from Formik to [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) some while ago and hadn't used Formik for a long time. But I think your performance problems are caused by the design of Formik.

Comment: i haven't used ```React Hook Form``` . that library dosen't have any perfomance problem on value Change?

Comment: @PPs React Hook Form tracks field values and changes on its own without changing react state. Updates on React state are only triggered when necessary, to get validation errors for example. They have good explanations on their website: https://react-hook-form.com/